# How to use database data on Event OnBeforeCreate

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I want to get the last data created on my database, more specifically the field called: "Saldo Atual" and after this get the form data field "Valor" and make a sum between this fields (the Old one "Saldo Atual" and the new "Valor") before create a new record and add this "Valor" and the sum of "Saldo Atual"+"Valor".

I don't know how to get the database last record

```
var saldoAtual = 

record.saldoAtual = saldoAtual + record.valor;
```

And I want to know if the second line it's correct to save the sum of "Saldo Atual"+"Valor"

Comment: I guess the first question should be do your records have a date_created field? I think without that you might be stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment, I think that your records will need to have a Date_Created field. Then in your onBeforeCreate event the following script should work (this is untested, so you need to do your own testing):

```
var query = app.models.YourModelTheSameAsYourEventModel.newQuery();
query.sorting.Date_Created._descending();
query.limit = 1;
var lastrecord = query.run();

record.saldoAtual = lastrecord.saldoAtual + record.valor; //You may need to use lastrecord[0].saldoAtual

record.Created_Date = new Date();
```

Try that and do some testing to see if this yields your desired output.

Comment: I tryed to do this on my appmaker and is getting this error:      

TypeError: Cannot read property "modelMovCaixa" from undefined. at models.modelMovCaixa.onBeforeCreateEvent:1
                                   
Creating new record: (Error) : Cannot read property "modelMovCaixa" from undefined.
at models.modelMovCaixa.onBeforeCreateEvent:1
at novaMovimentacao.Content.Form2.Form2Footer.Form2SubmitButton.onClick:1:19
                                        
Creating new record failed.

Comment: @ViniciusBelegi Did you end up figuring out what was causing the error?